# Creating tooltip in ms access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form and the user must have horizontal scroll. Users would like to see two text boxes in right side and left side of the form, but they cant see both of them at the same time. only half of the firs textboxe and the second textbox complete

What I thought is to have a tooltip for the first textbox, then user can see the second textbox and with tooltip, information in the first textbox.

How can I create a tooltip in vba Access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options, [StatusBarText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845617%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property and [ControlTipText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821170%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that you can use to provide user feed back.

See also [TextBox Members (Access)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822556%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wnt to have the text in Textbox as tooltip text. If I am writing `Textbox1.Text` in ControlTip Text, I cant get the text in the text box as tool tip

Comment: In that case, consider Default Value for new records, or simply setting the text of the textbox in the Enter property. Please note that the Text property is only available when a control has focus. I wonder why you do not wish to use StatusBarText and direct the user to take note of the status bar?